# Newtonsoft.Json DeserializeObject not working

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a very simple JSON file:

```json
[
  {
    "smbshare": {
      "name": "Backup",
      "path": "\\linuxserver\backup"
    },
    "smbshare2": {
      "name": "Tools",
      "path": "\\linuxserver\tools"
    }
  }
]
```

My model class:

```cs
public class SmbShare
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get;set; }

    [JsonProperty("path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

And the SmbController

```cs
public class SmbController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("smbshares.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            List<SmbShare> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SmbShare>>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

The list `items` contains only one object but with empty values (null / 0).

Any hints why the mapping doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mismatch between your JSON and your data structure:

`List<SmbShare>` would be represented in JSON as follows:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Backup",
    "path": "\\linuxserver\backup"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tools",
    "path": "\\linuxserver\tools"
  }
]
```

You need to either update your JSON file or your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON does not represent `List<SmbShare>`, but a list of objects containing `SmbShare` properties. One way to handle this is to use `Dictionary<string, SmbShare>` (otherwise you will need to have a class with `smbshare` and `smbshare2` properties):

```cs
var json = """
[
  {
    "smbshare": {
      "name": "Backup",
      "path": "\\linuxserver\backup"
    },
    "smbshare2": {
      "name": "Tools",
      "path": "\\linuxserver\tools"
    }
  }
]
""";

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, SmbShare>>>(json);
Console.WriteLine(list.First().First().Value.Name); // Prints "Backup"
```

Or if you can - just fix the JSON to:

```cs
[
  {
      "name": "Backup",
      "path": "\\linuxserver\backup"
  },
  {
      "name": "Tools",
      "path": "\\linuxserver\tools"
  }
]
```

Then it will be deserialized to `List<SmbShare>` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The class doesn't match your JSON. You're deserializing an array of one object with two properties, `smbshare` and `smbshare2`. The serializer doesn't know that you intend these to be array elements. To get the result you expect, you will have to use a [custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: _"To get the result you expect, you will have to use custom JsonConverter"_ - there are easier options to handle the situation than using custom converter.